# memory not free properly when fork

Tags: c, memory-management, child-process

I can't see what i'm doing wrong, this output from valgrind say that i did not free properly the variable, but when i remove the fork from code i can see that this is free properly, so what is wrong is the fork and i dont know how to fix it.
**Resume from code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void    handler(int sig);

void    main(void)
{
    struct sigaction    sb;
    int                 pid;
    int                 ret;
    char                *demo;

    memset(&sb, 0, sizeof(sb));
    sb.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sb, NULL);
    demo = strdup("test");
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            free(demo);
            demo = NULL;
            demo = strdup("blabla");
        }
    }
    waitpid(pid, &ret, 0);
    if (demo != NULL)
    {
        free(demo);
        demo = NULL;
    }
    return ;
}

void    handler(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    printf("ctrl+c");
    exit(130);
}
```

**Valgrind command: valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all**

**output**

```
==4573== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4573== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4573== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4573== Command: ./a.out
==4573==
^Cctrl+c==4573==
==4573== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4573==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==4573==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,029 bytes allocated
==4573==
==4573== 5 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==4573==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4573==    by 0x48F850E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==4573==    by 0x1092B2: main (in /mnt/c/projects/test/a.out)
==4573==
==4573== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4573==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4573==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4573==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4573==    still reachable: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==4573==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4573==
==4573== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4573== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
ctrl+c                                                                                                      ==4574==
==4574== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4574==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4574==   total heap usage: 305,565 allocs, 305,565 frees, 2,139,970 bytes allocated
==4574==
==4574== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4574==
==4574== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4574== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why is there a while(1) ?

Comment: Compliing with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` often give a faster result than running with `valgrind`.

Comment: @TonyTannous the main code is similar but is too big so i resumed puting this while but the aim is close this loop in fork using ctrl+c but have this output in valgrind in both code

Comment: Are you aware sigint is sent to the parent process as well?

Comment: "Still reachable" isn't really an issue...

Comment: But calling `printf()` and `exit()` in a signal handler are. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html